# Trying to escape the backslash in this bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

The following bash script takes any input of numbers between 0-100 and prints out an average of the numbers to the screen. The script also has input validation that won't allow anything but a number between 0-100 and a q or Q. Once you enter a q or Q it computes the results and outputs to the screen. Input validation also checks to make sure there are no null values entered, special characters entered and that there are no number/letter combinations, special character/number combinations etc. entered.

The only problem I have is with the backslash character. The backslash is escaped in this script and when I run the script and enter a backslash it pauses and requires you to press return for the script to continue. Seems like the script still works but I'm curious about why it pauses. Most of the recommendations I've seen on this on this site have been to escape the backslash with more backslashes but that doesn't work.

```
#! /bin/bash

AVERAGE="0"
SUM="0"
NUM="0"
clear

while true; do
    echo -n "Enter your score [0-100%] ('q' for quit): "; read SCORE;

    if [[ "$SCORE" == *[a-pA-pr-zR-Z]* ]] ||
       [[ "$SCORE" == *['!'\\@#\$%^\&*()_+~\`\-=\[\]\{\}\|:\;\'\"\<\>,.?/\\]* ]] ||
       [[ -z "$SCORE" ]] ||
       (( "$SCORE" <  "0" )) || (( "$SCORE" > "100" ))
    then
        echo "Be serious.  Come on, try again: "
    elif [[ "$SCORE" == [qQ] ]]; then
        echo "Average rating: $AVERAGE%."
        break
    else
        SUM=$[$SUM + $SCORE]
        NUM=$[$NUM + 1]
        AVERAGE=$[$SUM / $NUM]
    fi
done

echo "Exiting."
```

Comment: also how do I also have it check for any alphanumeric entry and prompt them to reenter?

Answer (score 2):

Use `read -r` to disable backslash escaping, which is enabled by default.

```
Options:
  -r   do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
```

Comment: thanks the read -r fixed the problem with the backslash. now I have another problem with entering any number followed by the letter q, it breaks the script.

Comment: `A-p` should be `A-P`.

Comment: in other words how would I have this script check for an alphanumeric entry and make the user reinput the number correctly?

Comment: Put the `== [qQ]` check first, and make the big `if` statement second. Then you can simplify `*[a-pA-pr-zR-Z]*` to `*[a-zA-Z]*`.